# AOSP + annotation processor + jack

Tags: java, android, android-source, annotation-processing, android-jack-and-jill

How to get libraries requiring annotation processor (such as butterknife, dagger etc.) to be usable for an app in AOSP (N, in my case)?

Jack seems to support annotation processor according to [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/jackandjill), but I can't find the proper flags to make it generate the files and add them to the classpath.

That functionality was added to gradle, but what's the equivalent for AOSP?